# Module not found: Can't resolve '@mui/material/utils' : (v5, which included a name change.)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I can see this error when I attempted to import some Icons from Material UI.
I installed some modules as advised, but still not fixed.

package.json

```
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.0.1",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.49",
```

I attempted to install  /utils by using the following command,

```
$ npm install @mui/material/utils
```

ERROR:

```
npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "@mui\material\utils" as it does not 
contain a package.json file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Han\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-10-03T21_47_03_649Z-debug.log
```

Is there anything I missed?

**After some reserch, I removed "@material-ui/core" and
install "@mui/core" instead. I assume this error comes up since there is name changed from material to mui?

```
    "@mui/core": "^5.0.0-alpha.49",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.0.1",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.49",
    "@mui/utils": "^5.0.1",
```

Thanks.

Comment: did you try to install the main package? https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mui/material

Comment: @Sysix It Works! I thought it should work only if I install above. lol I added main package and it fixed. Thanks Sysix!!

Comment: Material-UI about a week ago finally released their v5, which included a name change. You should ensure you are either sticking to the v4 dependencies, or upgrade them all to v5 compatible dependencies.

Answer (score 63):

Try this command
`npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled`

See the [installation instructions](https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/installation/) for react mui.

Comment: Upvoted, but try to include an explanation in your answer too :)

Comment: yeah please dont give a helpful answer unless you explain yourself first

Comment: Added explanation.

Answer (score 31):

### Why does it happen?

This error happens when installing the [MUI icons package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mui/icons-material) **before** installing the [MUI component library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mui/material). The MUI icons package needs `@mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled` packages to work properly.

### Solution

Run one of the following lines

```
// with npm
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled

// or if you prefer yarn
yarn add @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try to install the main package.**

```
 npm i @mui/material
```

This will definitely solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

You can try installing the module if it isn't already!
Try running this in case you have `NPM`:

```
npm install @mui/icons-material
```

Or, with `Yarn`:

```
yarn add @mui/icons-material
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1  : npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled

Step 2 Import this file in your project :
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';

This will definitely solve your error

node -- version : v16.17.0
npm -- version : 8.15.0

Answer (score 0):

I added all the packages and it still didn't work, so I commented my imports and uncommented them and it worked. So if you imported them and it still doesn't work, give this a try or reset your IDE.